# How to recover permissions to library

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions

**Problem**
I accidentally deleted permissions to a list for all users (including myself - the admin)

**Goal**
I want to get access to the list back

**Details**
I broke the permissions on the library level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no way** to recover the custom permissions you granted in the past or the permissions the library had before remove them. What you can do is to inherit again permissions from the parent site. You can go to "permissions" settings for that library and click on "Delete unique permissions" to start inheriting again. Please, read carefully this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-permissions-for-a-SharePoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) from Microsoft Support to understand permission management in the right way.

Comment: I thought so...
Unfortunately, as far as I know, it is not possible to go to "permissions" settings for a library to which I do not have access, so it is impossible to delete those unique permissions. Am i right?

Comment: yes, you need to ask to the site owner, site collection administrator or SharePoint administrator

Comment: Is there a way to check who is the site owner or SP administrator_

Comment: If you have permissions to see the site collection or site permissions you will be able to access the owners' group and see the persons that are listed there. Just contact each of them until you have any positive response.